# How to make your computer fan quieter during voice/video calls without headphones?

Tags: audio, fan, cooling, microphone, video-streaming

Wearing headphones is an obvious solution to a noisy computer fan, since it takes the microphone much further away from the fan.

Turning off unnecessary applications is another way to help reduce noise from a computer fan, since it will hopefully result in a CPU with lower temperature, and the OS will adjust the fan speed down.

Are there any other tricks for making your computer fan quieter during voice/video calls?

Comment: You could consider replacing the fan and PSU so that its always quiet. For software, it is possible to use a different power scheme and limit the cpu performance. The pc will become slower, but the fans won't spin as fast.

Comment: Desktop or Laptop?  My desktop computer is not particularly near the microphone, so no issue. My laptop fan is very quiet. Make sure nothing but Zoom (or like) is running during these meetings. CPU should run < 5% more than 95% of the time in normal operation.

Comment: Some BIOS systems allow to adapt the correlation between temperature and fan speed or they provide a "silent mode" which reduces the maximum CPU power. Also make sure if you are running Windows that you don't used the energy mode "maximum performance". But in the end the best way to avoid these problems is not buying load computers (read reviews before busing a new PC).